# Join Points Layer to a Polygon Layer Grouped by Field - ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I want to join a points layer to a polygon layer and summarize the points that fall within each polygon layer by a similar attribute in one of the point layers field...

For example I have hundreds of points that have a 'count' field of a certain amount of visits to a gym and there is also a field that specifies if they are a 'member', 'guest', or 'punchcard holder' ('CustomerType'). I want to join all of the points to a polygon geography layer (census block group) and summarize the points layer grouped by that 'CustomerType' field. I want my final output to be the polygon layer and each feature have the number of 'punchcard holder', 'guest', 'member', etc. and a sum of the visit 'count' from all the points.

I've been able to join the points layer to polygon layer and get the total number of visits by a spatial join but not grouped by'customertype'.

Answer (score 1):

If you already joined the data over and it is just a visual grouping that you want displayed I would suggest just symbolizing (Categorized) it by 'customer type'.

If you are looking for a more concrete solution than I would suggest trying out these tools: 'Summarize Within', 'Summarize Points', or 'Aggregate Points'.